# Writing to head, but not via _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I would like to write to the HTML head element independently via the page view, not through the _Layout.cshtml as each page will require different scripts, meta data, titles etc. Can this be done in ASP.NET MVC 3, with C# / Razor?

```
@using Test.Models;
@model IEnumerable<Player>
<!--           
Put JavaScript, CSS etc... Into the page <head> here.
-->

    <h2>Index</h2>
    <table id="scores">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
        </tr>
    @foreach(Player p in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@p.name</td>
            <td>@p.age</td>
            <td>@p.gender</td>
        </tr>
    }
    </table>
    <canvas id="game" width="800" height="600">
        <p>Download a modern browser.</p>
    </canvas>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do this by using sections.  Go to your _Layout.cshtml and add a new section called head like this:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
@RenderSection("head", false)
</head>
```

The new section is added with the @RenderSection. Now in your individual views you can add content to the head like this:

```
@section head
{
<script type="text/javascript">
   //Your java script here
</script>
}
```

When the complete view is rendered the javascript would be rendered in the head section just below the link tag. You could put anything in there. For example, meta tags.

Comment: FYI, you have two quotations after 'text/javascript'

Comment: @Misha - Thx.  Removed extra quotation.

Answer (score 0):

```
var newHeadElement = createSomeElementOrString;
document.getElementsByTag("head")[0].appendChild(newHeadElement);
```

Comment: is this the only solution to append it using JavaScript? I was hoping for something utilizing the view engine or asp.nets built in functionality.

Comment: If you want to utilize the view engine then you should change your layout to accept conditional entries from each view in the head, kevin has a good suggestion in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [razor sections](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx)?